# Como utilizar Object.value em Vuex Getters module

Tags: vue.js, getters-setters, vuex, getters

em um arquivo .vue ou html do vue, eu posso utilizar um v-if com o seguinte trecho

```
Object.values(this.dialogs).filter((v) => v).length !== 0
```

e funciona como esperado mas em um arquivo .js mais precisamente em um arquivo do tipo getter do vuex existe um erro ao compilar informando que Object não é resolvido,
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu arquivo de paginação do Vuex é este para este caso

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import Modules from '@/plugins/vuex/modules'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default function () {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    modules: {
      Modules
    }
  })
  return Store
}
```

e o Modules é este

```
import state from '@/plugins/vuex/state'
import * as getters from '@/plugins/vuex/getters'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters
}
```

no caso, como posso fazer isso

```
const dialogs = (state) => {
  // isso aqui
  return Object.values(state.dialogs).filter((v) => v).length !== 0
  // isso aqui
}

export {
  dialogs
}
```

no getter?

---

Ok, fiz neste formato até receber uma resposta que seja melhor

```
const dialogs = (state) => {
  function Object (object) {
    for (var i in object) { if (object[i]) return false }
    return true
  }
  return Object(state.dialogs)
  // return Object.values(state.dialogs).filter((v) => v).length !== 0
}
```

não é tão bonito mas funciona, se existir uma forma mais bonita e menor como no exemplo que funciona no .vue, eu prefiro

Comment: No segundo trecho de código (`getter` do Vuex), o que aparece se você der um `console.log(state.dialogs)`?

Comment: @LuizFelipe funciona normalmente exibindo todos os dialogs dentro do objeto dialog, no meu caso, dialog: { states: false, loading: false, popup: false }; o que da erro é o Object.values que mostra como se precisar instalar

Comment: Seria legal se postasse o código do Vuex mais completo que apenas o trecho que desejas incluir.

Comment: o Vuex trabalha com modulos, estou utilizando o um modulo denominado para tal tarefa, este possui apenas este trecho definido para getters, porém, posso anexar o main sem problemas